# How to query Id of a field/Custom field from standard object using Tooling API in .net

Tags: query, standard-objects, fields, tooling-api, .net

How do I get the Id of the field on Standard object like Account, Opportunity & Custom Object and Custom Field Id using Tooling API in .net.

Answer (score 1):

The following query on the tooling REST API would return the data you required:

```
/services/data/v32.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT Id, DeveloperName, TableEnumOrId FROM CustomField
```